# Access violation error every time I make a change to source code in Embarcadero's C++ Builder XE8

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-xe8

I am working on debugging a very large program that takes a couple of minutes to build from scratch. 
Whenever I make the slightest change to the source code and try to rerun the program, I get an access violation error immediately upon launch. The way I have been getting around this is by cleaning the project as to delete all of the objs and then re-creating all of them at which point the program runs fine.
However, I don't want to keep wasting a couple of minutes every time I make a little change to the program. 
Is the compiler not creating the objs correctly for whatever reason or what exactly is going on here and is there a better solution?

I am using Embarcadero's C++ Builder XE8.

Thanks.

Comment: Try disabling Incremental Link in the project options, then clean and rebuild. Their incremental linker has always had problems like this for decades

Comment: @M.M That did the trick. Thanks.